# Highcharts polar wind rose chart with segments in trapezoid form

Tags: javascript, extjs, highcharts, extjs6.2

I am using extjs and highcharts to develop a wind rose chart. I need to display the data as trapezoids with straight edges, rather than the default display of the segments with arcs as delimiters. Here is an image of what I am trying to do

[image]

I have been able to integrate the highcharts object into my application using the wrapper provided by JoeKuan

However I am not seeing in the highcharts documentation how I can configure the polar chart columns into straight edged segments as seen in the image..

Here is a fiddle of the polar chart as it works currently.. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cosgravelisa/0mb1s1jd/)

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    data: {
        table: 'freq',
        startRow: 1,
        endRow: 17,
        endColumn: 7
    },

    chart: {
        polar: true,
        type: 'column'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Wind rose for South Shore Met Station, Oregon'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: or.water.usgs.gov'
    },

    pane: {
        size: '85%'
    },

    legend: {
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 100,
        layout: 'vertical'
    },

    xAxis: {
        tickmarkPlacement: 'on'
    },

    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        endOnTick: false,
        showLastLabel: true,
        title: {
            text: 'Frequency (%)'
        },
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.value + '%';
            }
        },
        reversedStacks: false
    },

    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '%'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            shadow: false,
            groupPadding: 0,
            pointPlacement: 'on'
        }
    }
});
```

All help greatly appreciated

Lisa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `type: 'area'` to achieve that visualization.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    data: {
        table: 'freq',
        startRow: 1,
        endRow: 17,
        endColumn: 7
    },

    chart: {
        polar: true,
        type: 'area'
    },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0mb1s1jd/1/

Comment: Thank you so much, that is exactly what I was after :-)